# Echoing html with php code inside

Tags: php, html

```
<?php
$sample = 0;
    if($sample ==0)
    {   
        $displayinner = '<option value =' . $row['privilege_ID'] . '>' . $row['privilege_name'] . '</option>';
        $displayouter = '<td><label>Privileges:</label></td>
          <td><select name = "Privilege" id = "Privilege" multiple="multiple">
              <?php
                $PrivilegeNames = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM privilege");
                while($row = mysql_fetch_array($PrivilegeNames))
                    echo $displayinner;
              ?>
            </select></td>
          </tr>
          <tr>';
        echo $displayouter;
    }
?>
```

I only get a dropdownbox without any data inside it. Please help, what am i doing wrong?

Comment: You are doing everything wrong.

Comment: the sample is just a temp variable for me to use, i just set it to zero for now so that it will display. I just want to display the dynamic dropdown after it satisfies the if which for now is just a sample data.

Comment: Please, don't use `mysql_*` functions for new code. They are no longer maintained and the community has begun the [deprecation process](http://goo.gl/KJveJ). See the [**red box**](http://goo.gl/GPmFd)? Instead you should learn about [prepared statements](http://goo.gl/vn8zQ) and use either [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli). If you can't decide, [this article](http://goo.gl/3gqF9) will help to choose. If you care to learn, [here is a good PDO tutorial](http://goo.gl/vFWnC).

Comment: thanks, i will look into your advice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yeah that won't work - there's a lot of issues, your "template" code will be parsed which will cause errors, and you can't nest `<?php` blocks like that. To get what you want, try this for starters:

```
$displayouter = '<td><label>Privileges:</label></td><td><select name = "Privilege" id = "Privilege" multiple="multiple">';

$PrivilegeNames = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM privilege");
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($PrivilegeNames)) {
    $displayouter .= '<option value =' . $row['privilege_ID'] . '>' . $row['privilege_name'] . '</option>';
}

$displayouter .= '</select></td></tr><tr>';

echo $displayouter;
```

If you don't need the variable `$displayouter` later, you can just `echo` everything instead, or [break out of the PHP block](http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.alternative-syntax.php) entirely if this is template code. Note the use of `.=`, which appends data to the existing variable.

There's a lot of possible security holes here, but hopefully this helps to see some working code. Make sure to use [`htmlspecialchars`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.htmlspecialchars.php)  on all unknown HTML output, for one thing.

Comment: could you explain what you mean by security holes? I am a newbie in php. what are the issues of this code?

Comment: I shouldn't have said "a lot" - Primarily, I meant that whenever you output some unknown data to HTML, like a variable from an outside source like a database or text file, you should use `htmlspecialchars()` on it (always) so that any HTML characters are escaped, or else someone could run some javascript code by putting it in the database. It goes deeper than that (depends *where* you put the output into your HTML...), but it's a habit you should develop. I know it seems tedious but it's important.

Comment: ok I understand, place htmlspecialchars so escape characters so that they won't have a chance to access the database using javascript. Got it thanks

Comment: Err, something like that. For a very simple example, let's say someone entered `</html>` as a `privilege_name`. If you didn't escape it, it would break your page. If the variable contains HTML code (which you have no way of knowing) it can have bad effects, which include (but not limited to) executing javascript code - so always escape it.

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
$sample = 0;
if($sample == 0)
{   
    $displayPre     = '<td><label>Privileges:</label></td>
      <td><select name = "Privilege" id = "Privilege" multiple="multiple">';
    $displayPost    = '</select></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>';
    $PrivilegeNames = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM privilege");

    echo $displayPre;

    while($row = mysql_fetch_array($PrivilegeNames))
        echo '<option value =' . $row['privilege_ID'] . '>' . $row['privilege_name'] . '</option>';

    echo $displayPost;
}

?>
```

The inner php tags were not parsed correctly, try the code above, it implements the form with a pre and post part so you don't need to put a new php block inside the string

Comment: the data still doesnt show but the scrollbar is updated to have values

Answer (score 0):

Wesley Murch is close, but missing a few things: Quotes around the value, and using `htmlentities` to prevent XSS injection.

```
$displayouter = '<td><label>Privileges:</label></td><td><select name = "Privilege" id = "Privilege" multiple="multiple">';

$PrivilegeNames = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM privilege");
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($PrivilegeNames)) {
    $displayouter .= '<option value="' . htmlentities($row['privilege_ID']) . '">' . htmlentities($row['privilege_name']) . '</option>';
}

$displayouter .= '</select></td></tr><tr>';

echo $displayouter;
```

Answer (score 0):

I haven't tested syntax, but you have made a few  misplacements.

```
<?php 
$sample = 0; 
     if($sample ==0) 
     {    
          $displayinner = '<option value =' . $row['privilege_ID'] . '>' . $row['privilege_name'] . '</option>';
?>
          <td><label>Privileges:</label></td> 
             <td><select name = "Privilege" id = "Privilege" multiple="multiple"> 
<?php
                     $PrivilegeNames = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM privilege"); 
                     while($row = mysql_fetch_array($PrivilegeNames)) 
                          echo $displayinner; 
?>
                </select></td> 
             </tr> 
             <tr>
<?php
     } 
?>
```